# React Native - Firebase Storage links stored in Database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have done some small research and found out it might be a good idea to store the links of the files from Firebase Cloud Storage to the Firebase Database.

In short, I would like to implement a user gallery in my app. However, as a newbie I am not sure what is the best way to approach this. For example, some of the major questions that occurred to me were:

- *How should I call the fields of the links in the Database?*
- Say if they are uniquely generated ids, *how am I going to extract every single link from the database in React Native?*
- *What if the user had 500 links of images in his database folder, what would the best way to display them into the app be? Should they be directly loaded through some kind of a loop?*

I would really appreciate if someone who has such experience, could give me a brief explanation and tips with dos and don'ts.